# fetch error network on react native but working on postman

Tags: react-native, heroku, fetch, postman

I'm currently developping a react-native app. Working on the login part,
I successfully made my call on postman with the right return but when fetching through react-native android client I get absolutly no return when calling the heroku server or even a network failed error when running the server locally.

What am I doing wrong ? I got absolutly no logs back from the code under.

```
const payloadJson = JSON.stringify({
      email: 'julien@hypecode.com',
      password: 'password',
    })

fetch('https://alsatoju-dev.herokuapp.com/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: payloadJson,
      headers: {
        Accept: '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json()
    })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Can you make http request from your phone browser? If you can't that means you have a connection issue somehow.

Comment: @ridvanaltun yeah, looks like it's the case. I tried to do a blitzstack and it works fine...while i can't even start google chrome on my emulator :/